# Laravel: `php artisan app:name MyApp` caused an exception: Kernel does not exist

Tags: laravel

I wanted to change the `app.name` of my Laravel project, I run:

```
php artisan app:name Retro
```

But have error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Retro\Console\Kernel does >not exist in C:\photo->storage\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:779

Then, I edited `APP_NAME = Retro`, and run: 
`php artisan config:clear`

But it not working

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.7

Comment: try this ```php artisan clear-compiled && composer dump-autoload```

Comment: I tried ` composer dump-autoload ` and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

After update App name

```
php artisan app:name myname
```

Follow this commands

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear

composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: I tried ` php artisan cache:clear` .  But had the same error. I can't fix this

Comment: After change app name follows above 3 commands in sequence. have you tired `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Glad to help you. You can `Accept this answer` if you want. so other developers find solution easily